# Grouped Combinations Algorithm

Tags: algorithm, combinatorics

My nephew has a new business that unites business people for coffee and conversation. It's kind of like musical chairs. After a given amount of time, everyone gets up an moves to a different table. The idea is that everyone has to have the opportunity to talk to each person. He's trying to figure out how to do it with 16 people and 4 tables where everyone moves 5 times.

I wanted to figure out an algorithm to do that, but I found the problem is much more challenging than I imagined at first. To simplify it, I worked out how to do it with 6 people and 3 tables. It can be represented as follows:

```
Step 1: (1, 2), (3, 4), (5, 6)
Step 2: (1, 3), (2, 5), (4, 6)
Step 3: (1, 4), (2, 6), (3, 5)
Step 4: (1, 5), (2, 4), (3, 6)
Step 5: (1, 6), (2, 3), (4, 5)
```

One possibility, which wouldn't be very efficient, would be to generate all the possible combinations and eliminate any that are mutually exclusive. However with odd combinations, that wouldn't be possible. For example, if there were 6 people with only 2 tables, there would be two people sitting at the same table more than once. Of course, the idea of the algorithm is to have everyone meet at least once in the shortest number of steps.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is called the [social golfer problem](http://www.maa.org/editorial/mathgames/mathgames_08_14_07.html#g16o4d5). The link goes to a solution for the 16-person, 4-table case, reproduced here.

```
ABCD EFGH IJKL MNOP
AEIM BFJN CGKO DHLP
AFKP BELO CHIN DGJM
AGLN BHKM CEJP DFIO
AHJO BGIP CFLM DEKN
```

This problem is in general very hard; solutions are found either by mathematical constructions that do not work for all parameter settings or by lengthy constraint satisfaction computations.

Answer (score 1):

Pé, I saw you are also interested in APL, so you may like an APL algorithm to do this:

http://dfns.dyalog.com/n_pmat.htm

Comment: Thanks! I was going to try to find my own solution, but I'll check that out. Trying to solve it in PHP, I had to find a bitwise algorithm for expand. So when I started learning APL, I was happy to find that expand is already built it.

Comment: Oh well, I must be such a pain to do this in HPH! That's why I love APL so much :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you are looking for for a **6 person group**...

```
Session 1   Table 1   #1  &  #6   
Session 1   Table 2   #2  &  #5    
Session 1   Table 3   #3  &  #4   

Session 2   Table 1   #2  &  #3   
Session 2   Table 2   #6  &  #4   
Session 2   Table 3   #5  &  #1   

Session 3   Table 1   #3  &  #5   
Session 3   Table 2   #4  &  #1   
Session 3   Table 3   #6  &  #2   

Session 4   Table 1   #2  &  #4   
Session 4   Table 2   #1  &  #3    
Session 4   Table 3   #5  &  #6   

Session 5   Table 1   #4  &  #5   
Session 5   Table 2   #3  &  #6   
Session 5   Table 3   #1  &  #2
```

Copy & Paste the list above into your own word processor, then use
Search and Replace to change the numbers to names.

If they meet once a week, it will take 5 weeks to meet each other once.
If they meet all on one day, and each individual meeting lasts 15 minutes,
you will need 5 - 15 minute sessions (1 hour & 15 minutes total).
You can also add a date, time and place to each meeting.
If your meetings go on longer than 5 weeks, simply copy the stack
to make another 5 week session.

For a **16 person group**, and have all 16 meet the other 15 people once, you would need 8 tables and could use 10 or 15 minute sessions. All 16 individuals would meet with the other 15 participants one-on-one, one time.
The first and second sessions would look like this:

```
Session  1  Table  1   #1  &  #2
Session  1  Table  2   #3  &  #4
Session  1  Table  3   #5  &  #6
Session  1  Table  4   #7  &  #8
Session  1  Table  5   #9  &  #10
Session  1  Table  6   #11  &  #12
Session  1  Table  7   #13  &  #14
Session  1  Table  8   #15  &  #16

Session  2  Table  1   #10  &  #5
Session  2  Table  2   #4  &  #1
Session  2  Table  3   #2  &  #6
Session  2  Table  4   #12  &  #7
Session  2  Table  5   #8  &  #3
Session  2  Table  6   #14  &  #9
Session  2  Table  7   #16  &  #11
Session  2  Table  8   #13  &  #15

Continues Sessions 3 thru 15
```

The 16 person rotation group is quite large.  The meeting time can be
reduced to say 10 minutes which would require 15-sessions of 10 minutes
each over a 2:30 minute time frame, or spread it out over two or more days.
After a rotation schedule is built, the last thing is to assign actual
names using global search & replace. With the cursor at the top of the list
search for **#1** and replace with **Bill Jones**. Do the same for the others.

There are numerous ways of re-arranging the dates, time elements for a 16 element
round robin team building schedule such as this. The following is an examples of 
what completed single lines would look like.

```
Dec 16 Monday
Session  1  Table  1  9:00am  Bill Jones & Fred Johnson
Session  1  Table  2  9:00am  Jack Wilson & Sarah Ford
Session  1  Table  3  9:00am  Larry Peterson & Sue Falvey 
etc.
```